# Fibonacci in python, recursively into a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I am practicing with some code, and one thing I am trying to do is have the Fibonacci sequence placed recursively into a list. I have managed to do it without recursion, but that is not too difficult. Thank you to anyone who can offer any help.

```
#python 2

arr = [1, 1]
n=15
def Fib(n):
  tmp = arr[-1] + arr[-2]
  if n == 0:
    return 0 #base case 1
  elif n == 1:
    return 1  #base case 2
  else:
    return Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2) #recursive call
  arr.append(tmp)
  return arr
Fib(n)
print arr
```

Comment: please tell us more about how you are trying to attempt this, what result(s) you have so far and any error message or difficulties you are encountering...thanks

Comment: Looks like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a dry run of your code. You will find that

```
arr.append(tmp)
  return arr
```

The above code never gets executed as it returns the answer before in one of the if-else conditions.

The following code helps:

```
arr = []
n=15
def Fib(n):

  if arr[n] != -1:
    return arr[n]
  if n == 0:
    arr[0] = 0
    return 0 #base case 1
  elif n == 1:
    arr[1] = 1;
    return 1  #base case 2
  else:
    arr[n] = Fib(n-1) + Fib(n-2);
    return arr[n];

for i in range(n+1):
    arr.append(-1);
Fib(n)
print arr
```

What I am doing is that initially I am assigning -1 to all the indexes in the list telling that this particular state has never been visited. Once, I visit a particular state, I store its solution in the arr at that index. And if the solution state has been visited and is encountered again, I straight away return the solution possible at that index without recursing further on it.

Comment: do you know of a way where arr=[] could be within the function?

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 you can do an efficient recursive implementation using `lru_cache`, which caches recently computed results of a function:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(100)
def fib(N):
    if N <= 1:
        return 1
    return fib(N - 1) + fib(N - 2)

[fib(i) for i in range(10)]
# [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

This also works without the cacheing, but computational complexity is exponential in `N` for that case.

Answer (score 0):

faster way

```
def Fib():
    a,b = 0,1
    yield a
    yield b
    while True:
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield b

from itertools  import islice 

for i in islice(Fib(),15):
    print i
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. (It doesn't use recursion at all.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
def fib(n, sofar=[]):
  if n == 0:
    return sofar

  if len(sofar) < 2:
    return fib(n-1, sofar + [1])

  return fib(n-1, sofar + [sofar[-1] + sofar[-2]])

print(fib(11))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this:

```
    def fibonacci(n):
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        elif n == 1:
            return 1
        else:
            return fibonacci(n-2) + fibonacci(n-1)

    number = int(input("Enter the range of numbers: "))

    result = []
    start = 1
    for num in range(start, number+1):
        result.append(fibonacci(num))
    print(result)

    # Output
    [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following recursive method.

```
# Where 'n' is the max range of a number in Fibonacci series 
def fibo(n, a = 0, b = 1, fib = []):
    if b < n:
        fib.append(b)
        a, b = b, a + b
    else:
        return fib
    return fibo(n, a, b, fib)


print fibo(20)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```